# Speech recognition and synthesis sample doesn't work when deployed on IoT version 10.0.10586

Tags: windows, uwp, iot

On the newest version of Windows IoT, the Speech recognition and synthesis sample stopped working. Continuous dictation (number 7 in the menu), goes Idle right away once I press "Dictate" button.
Microphone permission is on, and everything stayed the same from the 10.0.10240 release which worked perfect.

Note that it only doesn't work when deployed to Minnow Board or Dragon Board, but works locally on the Windows PC.

Any idea on what could cause that? I've tested multiple times and when I revert back to 10.0.10240 it starts working again, but it doesn't work on the newest release.

Github link to the Microsoft Sample UWP C# project: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis

Thanks

Comment: Everybody facing the same problem. With the build 10586, speech recognition does not work on RPi2 anymore. When I revert back to old 10240, it works like charm. Hope, they may resolve in next build. :)